# Google Vision API - Project not passed

Tags: gcloud

I am trying to use the Google VISION API and I want to use the programm "quickstart.py" at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/cloud-client/quickstart/quickstart.py.
I have created an account at Google itself and set the variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS". I created a test project then stored my credentials locally.

However, when running the application I first authenticated via "gcloud auth application-default login" and run the code of the application. But unfortunately I received the message
"OSError: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment".

What change do I need to make in order to run this example?

Thanks,
Andi

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This worked for me while using Colab:

`import os
os.environ["GCLOUD_PROJECT"] = "my-project-1234"`

Answer (score 10):

This will look for `GCLOUD_PROJECT` in environment variables, if `GCLOUD_PROJECT` has not been set, then set it to `"my-project-1234"`

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("GCLOUD_PROJECT", "my-project-1234")
```

Answer (score 7):

Set environment variable `GCLOUD_PROJECT` to be equal to your project name.

Terminal: `$ export GCLOUD_PROJECT=my-project-1234`

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had this error and got another error when I ran `gcloud auth list` (`internal error, please report: running "google-cloud-sdk.gcloud" failed: cannot create transient scope: DBus error "System.Error.E2BIG": [Argument list too long]`), so I rebooted the machine and that fixed it.